# How to get the list of "objects" from a queryset in a Foreign Key relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-2.0

How can I get the list of objects from a Foreign Key realationship queryet? 
(as when you loop through a list using "for x in foo:print(x)")

code below:

```
class class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='typecourses')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)

class Module(models.Model):                                                         
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    courses = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='courses', null=True)
```

Below are the two queries I have tried in the "views", they both output the same results as querysets.

```
1/ module_taken = list(Course.objects.get(id=1).courses.all())
2/ module_taken = Module.objects.select_related('courses').all()
```

result:

```
<QuerySet [<Module: Foo>, <Module: Bar>]>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So why can't you do `for x in module_taken: print(x)`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried it. it would print in the console (terminal) the exact value i am looking for. In this case "Foo" and "Bar". But my next problem was not being able to grab those value and render them inside the context. lets say in a function class based views 'return render('snippets/detail.html', context)'. I was not able to find a way to pass it to the context because print does "print".

Comment: Er, what? print is for debugging. Why can't you pass `module_taken` to the context and do whatever you need to in a loop in the template? I just don't understand your problem.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you. honestly, I totally forgot that I could loop through the queryset inside the template.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is:

```
course_taken = Course.objects.get(id=1)
```

Now course taken contain the object course with id=1

```
modules_course = course_taken.courses.all()
```

Now modules course contain a queryset with all the modules with course_taken as their Foreign key, notice that courses is just the name you put in related name